# Why is it required to remove jre from installed jre

Tags: java, eclipse

While working with eclipse i always see that we remove installed jre from the path and add jdk instead.
I wanted to know why do we do it everytime we start a new project.

Comment: I don't know if that's necessary. At least in the past, Eclipse had its own compiler and it was rather faster than the JDK one

Comment: Not sure I understand. Eclipse prefers a JDK because then it can show you the Javadoc and source code of Java classes, JREs don't have that. All recent releases of Java are JDK only anyway.

Comment: Note: In the Preferences the "Java > Installed JREs" page can be used to set the default JDK/JRE used for new projects.